# If a frequent flyer program allows you to earn "250 award miles per stay" at a hotel, then does staying for more nights increase the miles?

Tags: hotels, loyalty-programs

So the Best Western Hotel Rewards program rewards 250 award miles per "stay" for American Airlines, Delta, and United Airlines. I'm just wondering though - is it 250 award miles for each night, or do you get awarded 250 award miles for the entire length of the stay?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Per stay means no matter how many nights. That said, people who are close to a threshold for number of stays (and who travel light) have been known to book two hotels in the same city and move back and forth between them each day to get 5 separate stays out of a 5-night trip. It's annoying to check in and out like that and I wouldn't do it for 250 more miles a day, but that's what it would take.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that most hotel loyalty programs count it as one stay if you check out and in again the same day - you need to spend a night in a different property to have it counted as an additional stay

Comment: Exactly, that's why you need to check out of A and go move over to B for the night, then the next day check out of B and move back to A, etc.